# Automate: export runnable jar, by Launch Configuration, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, jar

I develop Java code using Eclipse. When I want a runnable jar I point and click in the GUI like this:

File->Export->Runnable Jar -> Launch Configuration (select MainTest) --LibraryHandling (extract required libraries into generated JAR)

I want to do this automatically, how can I do this in bash?

Comment: You might want to use [ant](http://ant.apache.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what is in your project and what dependencies you have, this could be pretty complex using the command line tools Java provides. [The Java tutorial is pretty good in explaining the usage of the related tools that ship with Java to create jars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html), but I think most people suggest using a build tool like Maven or Gradle for command line builds.

If you're using the jar tool though, the most basic example for the jar tool with a runnable Main class being specified is:

```
jar cmf existing-manifest jar-file input-file(s)
```

where existing-manifest would be your manifest file that specifies your main class.

Comment: I don't want to make it complicated. Just not click in the GUI. Eclipse can still be running. I know about the jar cmf. Thanks you anyway

Comment: I don't think there is command line interface to the Eclipse build tools. Most people separate their build process from their IDE, and use Maven/Gradle/or Ant to build, either with the command line interface or through an IDE plugin. That sounds exactly like what you want.

Comment: No that's not what I want. I know what I want... The reason I want this is to be able to export my program as a jar file as easy as I can press the play button in eclipse without any extra programs. Automatically exporting when I run the program would also work. In the end I want to build the jar, upload it to my server through scp and then execute it. Editing an ant script for every little program is not a good solution. This is no big enterprise solution project. Just small java programs with 1-3 classes

Comment: Okay, originally you implied you wanted a command line interface because your original question asks for a bash solution, but if you want a button then the same solution still applies. You could download a plugin to a popular build tool like mentioned, and start having your IDE use that build tool's build process instead of it's own. You'll have the button in your IDE that does the exact build process you want (whatever you specify in the build script), with the bonus of having the bash command line interface if needed in the future. The build script doesn't really change overtime.

Comment: Some of the build tools support extra scripting that can allow you to push to servers and that sort of thing too. It sounds like you'll need scripting of some kind to do specific things like that.

Comment: The problem with those tools is that it is not as automatic as the export function in eclipse. Eclipse can export the build script in ant but I want it to automatically figure out what classes it need just by giving it the filename of the file containing the main function. I would prefer to invoke this by a script but a button that  makes the jar and then invoke a script to make use of it would also work.

Comment: The same functionality as : File->Export->Runnable Jar -> Launch Configuration (select MainTest) --LibraryHandling (extract required libraries into generated JAR). But in a script(invoked by button or not)

Comment: I know how to do the rest. Just want to create a jar in a most simple way.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have much experience in Ant, but in my experience with Gradle and Maven you either can have all your source files in the directory it expects or tell it what directory, and after that you only have to specify what main class. I never had to specify each source file one by one (unless you are saying you want to export sometimes a subset of classes that are only needed, not sure how much build tools support this). Same amount of work as Eclipse, in Eclipse you also still have to specify library dependencies and that sort of thing. I don't have any more suggestions though, sorry.

Comment: I will give Gradle a shot. I could maybe build a function that: if the program is executed from my eclipse enviorment, it builds itself, else it does what it is supposed to do:/

Comment: That should be possible. There should be a good enough Gradle plugin for Eclipse I'd imagine that has a build and run option, as Eclipse already has that. The plugin might, depending on how it's made, take over the build buttons that Eclipse's build system would have otherwise used too, so you might have the same interface to build/run as you always have.